# 'Lie correspondence' for formal power series in non-commuting indeterminates

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, power-series

This is related to [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398002/groups-associated-with-infinite-dimensional-lie-algebras) of mine. I would like an argument or a reference (or a missing hypothesis if needed) for the following.

> Let  $\mathbb{F}\langle\langle \alpha\rangle\rangle$ and $\mathbb{F}\langle\langle \beta\rangle\rangle$ be the algebras of formal power series in the given sets of non-commuting indeterminates over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic zero. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be the respective Lie subalgebras
> with zero constant term. Let
> $G$ and $H$ be the subgroups of the groups of units of the respective algebras consisting of the elements with constant term equal to 1. (So $\log$ maps $G$ bijectively onto $\mathfrak{g}$ and similarly for $H$.)
> Let $\Phi:G\to H$ be a homomorphism, and set $\phi=\log\Phi\exp$. Assume that $\phi(aX)=a\phi(X)$ for all $a$ and $X$.
> Then $\phi(X+Y)=\phi(X)+\phi(Y)$.

Let's recall the set-up in the classical case of matrix Lie groups and Lie algebras. Under suitable hypotheses there is a 1-1 correspondence between Lie group homomorphisms $\Phi:G\to H$ and Lie algebra homomorphisms $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra corresponding to $G$, and similarly for $\mathfrak{h}$: they are related via $\exp\phi=\Phi\exp$. The proof that a Lie algebra homomorphism $\phi$ gives rise to a Lie group homomorphism $\Phi$ is fairly neat. A key step is to show that $\log(\exp(\phi(X))\exp(\phi(Y)))=\phi(\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y)))$, which is a consequence of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

To show that $\Phi$ gives rise to a suitable $\phi$, the key step this time is to show that $\phi$ is additive which reduces to the identity

> $\Phi\exp(\log g + \log h)=\exp(\log\Phi(g)+\log\Phi(h))$,

but this seems to be trickier to prove in the situation I'm interested in. Even if one inverts the BCH formula (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32281/inverse-of-baker-campbell-hausdorff) and [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32281/inverse-of-baker-campbell-hausdorff/32306#32306)), the required identity is not obvious to me. (In the notation of that answer, we would need the identity $\Phi A(g-1,h-1) = A(\Phi(g)-1,\Phi(h)-1)$.)

The proof in Brian C. Hall's book to handle the classical case uses $\left(e^{\frac{X}{m}}e^{\frac{Y}{m}}\right)^m$ as an approximation to $e^{X+Y}$ and then involves taking $\lim_{m\to\infty}$, but unfortunately taking such limits doesn't seem to be valid in my situation. This could be remedied by assuming $\mathbb{F}$ is an ordered field and that $\Phi$ preserves limits in an appropriate sense, but I would like to avoid making extra assumptions if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't discount the $\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(e^{X/m} e^{Y/m}\right)^m = e^{X+Y}$ argument all too quickly. I'm pretty sure that each single coefficient (in front of a fixed word) of $\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(e^{X/m} e^{Y/m}\right)^m$ is a rational function in $m$, and thus its limit as $m \to \infty$ is defined algebraically, by replacing $m$ by $1/m$ and substituting $0$ into the (reduced) fraction. Is this limit not equal to the corresponding coefficient of $e^{X+Y}$? (The question is not rhetorical.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think the limit is the corresponding coefficient of $e^{X+Y}$ as you say, but I don’t see why this limit is respected by $\Phi$.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a very partial answer to the problem in the case your field $\mathbb{F}$ is either the reals or the complex numbers.
Then the result you are after is a consequence of the group of formal power series you are looking for actually forming an infinite-dimensional Lie group which is regular in the sense of Milnor (actually even $C^0$-regular).
The key observation here is that the groups are character groups of suitable Hopf algebras (of non-commutative polynomials), whence the relevant Lie theory for these objects was developed in the paper [Character groups of Hopf algebras as infinite-dimensional Lie groups](https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/aif.3059.pdf).

For regular infinite-dimensional Lie groups, there is a version of the Lie theorem which asserts (under the usual topological assumptions like connected, simply connected) the correspondence you are asking for (see Glockner's [Regularity properties of infinite-dimensional
Lie groups, and semiregularity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0715.pdf)).
Regularity asks to solve certain differential equations (whence the restriction to the reals or complex numbers since we can make calculus work there). I am thus cheating as I picked exactly the cases where calculus works to a certain degree.

I wonder though if one could not circumvent this in the case at hand. A lot of the arguments (see especially Appendix B of [Character groups of Hopf algebras as infinite-dimensional Lie groups](https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/aif.3059.pdf)!) exploit heavily the grading of the algebra of formal power series.

Comment: Many thanks for those insights and references. I will certainly take a look at those papers.